# How to implement scroll-triggered animations in Next.js 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, next.js, aos.js

I am wondering how to implement scroll-triggered animations in **Next.Js 13** properly.

I have tried to use a scroll-triggered animation library like **AOS**, but in order for it to work, it needs to be initialized inside a useEffect hook, which requires **client-side rendering**. Now all of that would be ok, if I was only using it for one component (and only for that component declaring client-side rendering via 'use client'), but that is not an option, since I want to make AOS accessible across **my whole application**, so that all components and parts of the page can consume it, and that, therefore, means, if Im getting this right, that everything would use client-side rendering (since I am declaring at the root (in order to be able to use useEffect)), which is not what I want.

Is there a better way of implementing this or am I just understanding this all the wrong way? I am new to Next.Js so I'm sorry if this question is more on the 'stupid' side, but I couldn't find, or figure out an answer so I decided to ask it over here. I will be happy to hear your answers. :)

Comment: Hey Gal, so you are correct on trying to avoid using "use client" and move on... For you specific scenario I can see 2 ways, one could be simple but requires testing another one should work as well but needs a little bit more coding. 1- You can try to lazy load AOS by creating a dummy component that returns a Fragment for example and then importing this dude on the top but lazy load it, so you'll end up having a good performance gain overall. Needs further testing

Comment: 2- Another approach would be to create a custom hook for this implementation and use the logic for the AOS (which I do not know about sorry) anywhere you want to.

Comment: @PedroMendes Thank you so much for the suggestion. I will try to implement one of theese aproaches and see how it goes! :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work by doing this:

1. Created a reusable component named AOS.jsx as below:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import AOS from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";

export default function AOSComponent({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {
    useEffect(() => {
        AOS.init()
    }, [])

    return <>{children}</>
}
```

2. On each page 'client' where I need the AOS features, I wrap the page elements within it as below:

```
'use client'
...
import AOSComponent from '@/components/AOS';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <AOSComponent>
      <div>
        Homepage
      </div>
    </AOSComponent>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For server-side rendering with the `App` directory, you can create a reusable client component for `AOS` and render the server component as children. Remember that, we use `NextJS` for server side rendering.

1. AOS client component:

```
'use client'
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import AOS from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";

export default function AOSComponent({
   children,
}: {
   children: React.ReactNode
}) {
   useEffect(() => {
       AOS.init()
   }, [])

   return <>{children}</>
}
```

> Now, you can use this component as a parent of any server component,
> and you don't have to create every page as a client component.

1. use the `AOSComponent` with a server component.

```
import AOSComponent from '@/components/AOS';

export default function Home() {
 return (
   <AOSComponent>
     <div>
       This component will render on the server!
     </div>
   </AOSComponent>
 )
}
```